# Displaying the item version history programmatically using Javascript

Tags: 2007, list, javascript, version-history

I have a SharePoint 2007 list that have version history enabled.

I am interested to know how do I view the version history of a item using Javascript (or JQuery).

Comment: FYI - I've added GetVersionCollection into the latest alpha on SPServices, but I don't think it's going to be as useful as you'd like. See spservices.codeplex.com/releases/view/77486

Comment: Thanks Marc. Actually, I found the GetVersionCollection that you added into the latest alpha1 on SPServices very useful as it allow me to track the version history of each item in the list. Well Done. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make things even simpler on yourself, I would recommend using [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com).

It has [full support for the `Versions` web service](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Versions&referringTitle=%24%28%29.SPServices) in both SharePoint 2007 and 2010, which enables you to call the `GetVersions` method exposed by that service.

For example:

```
$().SPServices({
    operation: "GetVersions",
    fileName: "http://spsrv2010/DocLib/file.txt",
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
        // Do other stuff...
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Danny, does it also get versions from items in a SharePoint 2007 List? (Cause I notice that it need to know a filename - which probably a file from a SharePoint 2007 Library, but does a item in a Sharepoint 2007 List have a filename?)

Comment: Larry - for a standard list, you will actually want to use the `GetVersionCollection` method of the `Lists` web service. Unfortunately, it doesn't look like SPServices has support for that particular method at this point. With that in mind, you may want to use dhanya's approach. The MSDN documentation for the `GetVersionCollection` method can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getversioncollection%28v=office.12%29.aspx

Comment: If you want a Web Service operation that isn't included in SPServices, please leave a message in the Discussions, and I'll get it in there for you.

Comment: @MarcDAnderson Thanks Marc, I posted a new discussion over there. (http://spservices.codeplex.com/discussions/284298)

Answer (score 0):

You can make ajax calls to version webservice http:///_vti_bin/versions.asmx

See the below link make ajax cal to webservice

http://sharepoint-snippets.com/ajax-calls-sharepoint-web-services-using-jquery/